# Why is prefix=/path/to/perllib not enough to set PERL5LIB?

Tags: perl

If I create a Perl module and install it as

```
perl Makefile.PL prefix=/path/to/perllib
```

Then I would expect to be able to set PERL5LIB to /path/to/perllib and the module be found. This doesn't seem to be the case. The module gets installed to /path/to/perllib/site_perl/5.8.5/, so that's what PERL5LIB has to be set to (or passed to "use lib").

Am I doing something wrong in how I install the modules or how I set PERL5LIB?

Answer (score 4):

You're conflating PREFIX= and LIB=.

A distribution consists of more than just modules. Documentation, for one, isn't installed in the same directory as the modules themselves. PREFIX= tells Perl the base path for all components.

LIB= tells Perl where to install modules.

Use (for example)

```
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=~ LIB=~/lib/perl5
```

Then you'd use

```
export PERL5LIB=~/lib/perl5
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that's how it works. The prefix indicates the root of the installation, but the library directories are usually somewhere deeper within that directory structure.

If you install multiple modules with the same prefix, they should all be able to use the same `PERL5LIB` value, though.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short, use [`INSTALL_BASE`](https://metacpan.org/module/ExtUtils::MakeMaker#INSTALL_BASE) instead of `PREFIX`.  It works more like the `--prefix` of other installers and creates a predictable install pattern.  Then you can set `PERL5LIB` to `<INSTALL_BASE>/lib/perl5` and go.

[ExtUtils::MakeMaker::FAQ](https://metacpan.org/module/ExtUtils::MakeMaker::FAQ) explains:

> The behavior of PREFIX is complicated and depends closely on how your Perl is
> configured. The resulting installation locations will vary from machine to machine
> and even different installations of Perl on the same machine. Because of this, its
> difficult to document where prefix will place your modules.
>
> In contrast, INSTALL_BASE has predictable, easy to explain installation locations.
> Now that Module::Build and MakeMaker both have INSTALL_BASE there is little reason
> to use PREFIX other than to preserve your existing installation locations. If you
> are starting a fresh Perl installation we encourage you to use INSTALL_BASE. If you
> have an existing installation installed via PREFIX, consider moving it to an
> installation structure matching INSTALL_BASE and using that instead.

Answer (score 0):

What version of perl? You should only have to specify the path up to 'site_perl'. For libraries not under site_perl, you should also specify the path up to 'perllib'. More recent versions of perl (5.8 or better?) are better at letting you specify only these two directories, without having to specify version and architecture directories.